# Slow MDADM Raid 5 reads/write speeds

Tags: gpt, mdadm, raid-5

I set up a Raid 5 array from 4x4TB drives with mdadm. But the writes/reads are quite slow and I want to find out why. It isn't CPU-bound as the CPU usage during I/O operations is only around 10%. I also have 16GB of RAM so that probably isn't an issue too.

The raw read/write speeds of plain drives are at around 130MB/s locally when tested out on my Windows machine.

But when using a `dd` write from `/dev/zero` the speed of the array is only around 60MB/s.

Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sde: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ASM1156-PM
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BD79C155-5BBE-11EB-8D66-D83BBFD957A0

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1    2048     264191     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sde2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3.7T Microsoft Storage Spaces


Disk /dev/sdd: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ASM1156-PM
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BD79C15A-5BBE-11EB-8D66-D83BBFD957A0

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1    2048     264191     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3.7T Microsoft Storage Spaces
```

Output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jun 12 15:06:35 2021
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 11720658432 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906886144 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Feb  6 17:41:49 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : filip-nas:0  (local to host filip-nas)
              UUID : 5fe2775a:a8877735:a7bb8365:2f102649
            Events : 16331

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       48        0      active sync   /dev/sdd
       1       8       64        1      active sync   /dev/sde
       2       8       16        2      active sync   /dev/sdb
       4       8       32        3      active sync   /dev/sdc
```

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: How comes /dev/sde and /dev/sdd are not configured the same as /dev/sdc and /dev/sdb?

Comment: Is the speed really ~130 MB/s for all of them, even the ones that are connected via USB? (I see "ASM1156-PM" in the model field.) And are they _at least_ using UAS?

Comment: vmstat may give some clues. My guess is a variant of "hurry up and wait" -ie a combination of waiting for all disks aand processing overheads.  Also, have you considered that you are using RAID5 out of spec with 4tb drives?  Why not use RAID10 and harvest speed increases and reliability (at the cost of 4tb)

Comment: @user1686 yes, i used to use them on my Windows machine and the speeds are comparable to native SATA speeds.

Comment: Though I have purchased a PCIe SATA expansion card in case that were the issue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've no idea if that causes a speed decrease. It's just partitioning.

Comment: @1234filip It's strange that /dev/sdc reports a disk model of a Seagate IronWolf drive, but /dev/sde reports a disk model of a USB-to-SATA bridge. Does the motherboard have four SATA sockets available without any bridge chips?